# Android Market to list my app on just one particular device or just on tablets. How?

Tags: android, model, google-play, restrict, tablet

I need to make an app available for just one particular device model (or alternatively for just tablets) on the Android Market.
Is that possible?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mix of uses-feature and sdk versions could get you part of the way but the current sdks doesn't have a tablet feature, possibly coming in the next release

Reto Meier recently wrote a devblog on uses-feature: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/10/five-steps-to-future-hardware-happiness.html