# How to support WVGA on an android app -- ONLY

Tags: android

I am developing an android game which I want to run Only on WVGA devices.
How can i restrict other resolution devices.

Normal screens, high density have WVGA device but low and medium density devices are also a part of it . How can i restrict my app to run on Large screen and normal screen (excluding low and medium density)

Regards

Comment: Take a look at this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940632/android-market-to-list-my-app-on-just-one-particular-device-or-just-on-tablets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `<support screens>` permission in your `Manifest` file as below:

```
     <supports-screens 
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="false" 
            android:smallScreens="false"/>
```

Please read this document link : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html